# Issue with python subprocess

Tags: python, rpi.gpio

I'm having some trouble with some code I'm working on. It should be obvious as to what it does in the code. Here is the python code I have:

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import subprocess
gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
gpio.setup(18, gpio.IN, pull_up_down=gpio.PUD_UP)
gpio.setup(2, gpio.OUT)
p2on = False
while True:
    input_state = gpio.input(18)
    if input_state == False:
        if p2on == False:
            subprocess.call(['say','The light is on'])
            p2on = True
        else:
            subprocess.call(['say','The light is off'])
            p2on = False
    if p2on == True:
        gpio.output(2, True)
    else:
        gpio.output(2, False)
```

The `say` command I have thrown in there is just an alias I setup for basic TTS. The `say` command works on it's own, and I have two .sh scripts that call those same say commands, the code works. However, when I try just calling the command directly as above instead of:

```
import os
os.system('sh /home/pi/on.sh')
```

I get an error. The `os.system` method works, but only if I call another script file, and that's just too messy. The error that I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "button.py", line 13, in <module>
    subprocess.call(['say','The light is on'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying say is an alias, not a command?  Is the alias available to the environment you are using?  Why not just use the command the alias points to?

Comment: Say just points to Speech.sh in my home directory. I have also tried both a subprocess and system of `sh /home/pi/Speech.sh the light is on`. Subprocess spat out a very similar error and os.system said there was a syntax error because of an unexpected (.

Comment: Well, I fixed it. Now I feel silly. It wasn't letting me do `os.system('./Speech.sh The Light is now on')` before, but after I added in `os.system('cd /home/pi')` before the `while` loop, it worked. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Aliases are something your shell interprets and runs.  It's not a system call.  That's why it works from your .sh scripts, but not this python script.

I would suggest changing your call to:

```python
subprocess.call(['/bin/sh', '-i', '-c', 'say', 'the light is ...')
```